# Is there a solution as to why the javax.swing import is not working on my Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I am creating a GUI on Eclipse using Java code. Everything in my code is fine except for some reason the java swing package is not being recognized by my IDE. I have used the correct imports and I am using JDK-17 which should include the swing package by default and yet the issue persists. I get the following error when I run my code: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
SwingUtilities cannot be resolved. It also mentions that the package in not accessible.

I'd appreciate any kind of help with this.

Here is my code [Java Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8dEk.png).
All of the imports are not accessible for some reason.

Comment: Have you added the JAR in class path ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to add external jars (lib/\*.jar) to an IntelliJ IDEA project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project)

Comment: Do you have a `module-info.java` in the project? If you do you are using the Java 9 module system and need to update the module-info.java to require the java.desktop module - or just delete it to stop using the module system.

Comment: If @greg-449 declines, you can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).